# Encrypting a Silverlight XAP File

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

According to this link: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/20489.aspx encrypting a XAP file is not possible.  However, obfuscating is, but according to them obfuscation is just a minor abstraction to getting data in a XAP file.

Can anyone, thoroughly, explain why?  Is this because a Machine Key is required to encrypt the data efficiently and that Machine Key is Freely available?  Or another reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the XAP has to be decrypted to run.

Let's say you encrypted your XAP.  For a user to be able to run it you will have to provide them the decryption key so they decrypt it.  Now they have access to your un-encrypted XAP file.

So encrypting a XAP would accomplish nothing.

Comment: Can you site any specific sources?  That's what I'm really looking for.  I actually know the reasons, but I need credible sources like MSDN or something like that to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

XAP file is nothing but a compressed collection of files. If you change the extension from .XAP to .ZIP you will be able to look at the contents inside the .XAP file!!

I don't know if this is possible or not but obfuscating the source (assembly) while building the solution could be of some help.